# Background image downloading in ios

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

how to start background image downloading from where its stopped before connection lost in iOS?
Can someone please help?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have code with ? any sample.....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can resume downloading the image from the same point where it was stopped and can save it locally in background cache.
You can use either one of the libraries mentioned below
[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage),
[TCBlobDownload](https://github.com/thibaultCha/TCBlobDownload)
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Thejaswi venigalla- can you please tell me any function of code for the same instead of using category?